# How do I return the array from loop completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I vary new for javascript world, I've a simple method like this

```
function foo(items) {
 var result = []
 // Assume under forEach statement take 2 sec per loop
 items.forEach(function(item) {
     setTimeout(function() {
         result.push(item + 2)
     }, 2000)
  }) 
  return result
}

console.log(foo([1,2,3,4]))
console.log("Done")
```

**Result:**

```
[]
Done
```

**Except output:**

```
[ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
Done
```

anyone can help me, Or explain me about asynchronous in javascript to resolve this problem.

Comment: It's because of the `setTimeout`. You're putting asynchronous code inside of a a synchronous loop. Can you get rid of the timeout?

Comment: Why do you need `setTimeout`? If you do need it check the linked question. It provides you with a detailed explanations on how you could handle async in javascript.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko @MaxBaldwin actually, In the loop take some time before `push` item into result, it example for query or something that take time.

Comment: @6LYTH3 Then you do need to check the linked question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```js
function foo(items) {
 var result = []
 // Assume under forEach statement take 2 sec per loop
 items.forEach(function(item) {
    // Create a promise for each async function
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(item + 2); // resolve the async function
       }, 2000);
     });
     result.push(promise); // push the promise into array
  }); 
  // Create one promise for all the promises and return
  return Promise.all(result) 
}
// Now, foo function returns a promise and then is called once the promise is resolved which contains the data
foo([1,2,3,4]).then((response) => console.log(response)).then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

As `setTimeout` is an ansync function i.e. it executes out of order, hence, as expected the output was an empty array (when the array was returned, no callback of setTimeout function was executed). You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for working with async function.

Comment: Great effort! Use `.map`

Comment: Look good for me, `foo([1,2,3,4]).then((response) => console.log(response)).then(() => console.log("Done"))`

Comment: @6LYTH3 - Agreed. Updated. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin - The idea was to understand the `async` function rather than doing some `addition in timeout`. There are many approaches for the same, I picked the one that was easy for me to explain :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `setTimeout` and it should work as you expect:

```
function foo(items) {
 var result = []
 // Assume under forEach statement take 2 sec per loop
 items.forEach(function(item) {
     result.push(item+2)
  }) 
  return result
}

console.log(foo([1,2,3,4]))
console.log("Done")
```

Returns `[3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: And use the `.map` or `.reduce` method if you just  want to return an array.

Answer (score -1):

## Code :

Uses `Array.map` to push elements in :

```js
function foo(items) {
 var result = []
 items.map(_=>result.push(_+2))
  return result
}
```

## Explanation :

```
function foo(items) { // start function
    var result = [] // the result array
 items.map(_=>result.push(_+2)) // map over array and for every element set it equal to that element + 2
  return result; // return resultant array
} // end function
```

## Alternate and better :

```js
foo = items => items.map(_=>_+2)
console.log(foo([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Really? `map` to push to external array. Why??? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko : Edited to add. Also why down-vote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, actually :) But I do agree with the downvoter: promoting `map` to do side effects is a bad idea.